# Concatenate two lists in Terraform 0.12 - concat()

Tags: terraform

I want to concatenate two arrays in Terraform 0.12. In my example there are public and private subnets. I want to assign them both to the same network access lists. Following code shortened:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "private" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
    tags = {
        subnet-type  = "private"
    }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "public" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
    tags = {
        subnet-type  = "public"
    }
}


resource "aws_network_acl" "networks" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

    subnet_ids = concat(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids, data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids)
    [...]
}
```

If I use the following outputs:

```
output "private_subnets" {
  value = data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids
}

output "public_subnets" {
  value = data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids
}
```

The following output is generated:

```
private_subnets = [
  "subnet-243zr427rhhfjseb9",
  "subnet-we789rh2438fchb6e",
  "subnet-092rz7g82fhhkui74",
]
public_subnets = [
  "subnet-12230qegvg764e9d",
  "subnet-123465svgvgf0d7e",
]
```

So everything should work. But the following error is given:

```
iptizer@machine:~/src/infra$ terraform12 apply
[...]

Error: Invalid function argument

  on nacls.tf line 19, in resource "aws_network_acl" "networks":
  19:     subnet_ids = concat(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids, data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids)
    |----------------
    | data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids is set of string with 3 elements

Invalid value for "seqs" parameter: all arguments must be lists or tuples; got
set of string.
```

Bug.. or what am I missing?

Comment: This looks like an interesting bug in Terraform core that `concat()` only works against lists and not sets. I don't see an obvious reason it couldn't work on sets rather than lists (other than the type check) but you probably want to raise this as an issue on https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues

Comment: Is very weird, indeed. While you dig into this, you can try casting the results to list (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tolist.html).

Answer (score 36):

Terraform 0.12 makes a stronger distinction between list and set values than 0.11 did, and includes some additional checks like this.

In this particular case, `concat` is failing in this way because concatenation requires all of the elements to have a well-defined order so that the result can also have a well-defined order. Sets are *not* ordered, so this check is in place to remind you to explicitly select a suitable ordering when converting to list, or to not convert to list at all.

In this particular case it doesn't seem that the ordering is particularly important, so the lexical ordering implemented by [`sort`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/sort.html) could be sufficient:

```
  subnet_ids = concat(
    sort(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids),
    sort(data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids),
  )
```

(Because the conversion from list set of string to list of string also imposes lexical ordering, this is functionally equivalent to [`tolist`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tolist.html) for string sets. I generally prefer `sort` here because it's a clue to a future reader that the result will be in lexical order.)

Another option is to say in the world of sets, and use [`setunion`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setunion.html) instead:

```
  subnet_ids = setunion(
    data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids,
    data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids,
  )
```

Since there should be no duplicates between these two lists it doesn't really matter which approach you use here, but for completeness I'll note that in the event that both of these sets contained the same subnet id the `setunion` operation would dedupe them, because each unique value can only appear zero or one times in a set.

---

At the time I write this, where `count` is still the dominant way to create one resource instance per item in a collection, converting to a list *eventually* is commonly required so that the individual instances can have a required order. [Once `for_each` is implemented](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17179), there will be an advantage to using sets rather than lists in situations like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "per_subnet_example" {
  # resource-level for_each is not implemented at the time of writing,
  # but planned for a future release.
  for_each = setunion(
    data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids,
    data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids,
  )

  # ...
}
```

When using `for_each` over a set instead of `count`, Terraform will identify each instance by the value from the set rather than by consecutive indexes, so one instance from this resource might have the address `aws_instance.per_subnet_example["subnet-abc123"]`, and that means that when elements are added and removed from that set Terraform can just create/destroy the corresponding individual instance rather than potentially recreating everything after the change in the ordered sequence.

Terraform providers are using sets like this in places where it makes sense in order to make this `for_each` pattern easier to use once it arrives, but unfortunately that means we need to write some extra explicit type conversions in the meantime in order to be explicit that we're working with these values in an sequence-like way rather than a set-like way.

Answer (score 2):

Already there is similiar issue reported for the same in terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws issues.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7522

and there is work around also mentioned for the same. For your scenario you can workaround like below

**Work Around #1**

```
locals {                                                            
  private_subnet_ids_string = join(",", data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids)
  private_subnet_ids_list = split(",", local.private_subnet_ids_string)
  public_subnet_ids_string = join(",", data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids)
  public_subnet_ids_list = split(",", local.public_subnet_ids_string)             
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "networks" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

    subnet_ids = concat(local.private_subnet_ids_list, local.public_subnet_ids_list)
    [...]
}
```

**Work Around #2**

```
resource "aws_network_acl" "networks" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

    subnet_ids = concat(tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids), tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids))
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just simplified the solution. When output subnet ids use aws_subnet.whatever[*].id

**1. In VPC module's output.tf use the below syntax**

```
output "private_subnet_ids" {
  value = aws_subnet.private[*].id
}

output "public_subnet_ids" {
  value = aws_subnet.public[*].id
}
```

**2. In the submodule definition use**

```
module "acl" {
  source                = "../.../anything"
  private_subnet_ids    = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.private_subnet_ids
  public_subnet_ids    = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.public_subnet_ids
  ....
  ... other options
}
```

or

```
module "acl" {
  source                = "../.../anything"
  private_subnet_ids     = module.vpc.outputs.private_subnet_ids
  public_subnet_ids    = module.vpc.outputs.public_subnet_ids
  ....
  ... other options
}
```

**3. Then, in the child module just use the following syntax**

resource "aws_network_acl" "networks" {
vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

```
subnet_ids = concat(var.public_subnet_ids, var.private_subnet_ids)
[...]
```

}